# echo OOP php method

Tags: php, oop

I had one lesson in OOP which included messaging between classes. On the tutorial, the guy just showed var_dump output version of that. I wanted to play with the code and change from var_dump to echo output, because it would me more useful in future. I just couldn't find any solution so you guys are my only option. Here's the code.

```
<?php

class Person {

    protected $name;

    public function __construct($name) 
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    } 
}

class Business {

    // adding Staff class to Business
    public function __construct(Staff $staff)
    {
        $this->staff = $staff;
    }

    // manual hire(adding Person to Staff) 
    public function hire(Person $person)
    {
        // add to staff
        $this->staff->add($person);
    }

    // fetch members
    public function getStaffMembers()
    {
        return $this->staff->members();
    }
}

class Staff {

     // adding people from Person class to "member" variable
     protected $members = [];

    public function __construct($members = []) 
    {
        $this->members = $members;
    }

    // adding person to members
    public function add(Person $person) 
    {
        $this->members[] = $person;
    }

    public function members()
    {
        return $this->members;
    }
}

// you can also create an array with this method

$bros = [
    'Bro', 
    'Zdenko', 
    'Miljan', 
    'Kesten'
];

// pretty simple to understand this part

$employees = new Person([$bros]);

$staff = new Staff([$employees]);

$business = new Business($staff);

var_dump($business->getStaffMembers());
// or the print_r, it doesn't matter
print_r($business->getStaffMembers());

?>
```

Comment: What's your question or issue? PS: You can't echo an array, you will only get `Array`.

Comment: Start with the manual on arrays http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Your implementation of those example classes is wrong - you're passing in arrays where the classes appear to expect individual entities

Comment: Why exactly do you say that `echo` would be more useful than `var_dump()`? They're both useful; they do different things.

Comment: Thanks for ignoring us all up here (*you're right, it is sarcasm*) and having learned nothing, but thrown a mere fish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to loop through the array and echo out every single value.

```
$array = $something //your assignment here
foreach($array as $key => $value ){
    echo "$key => $value\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot :D it works now